# XmlElementName - Change during runtime

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I am implementing a class object that is serializable.

something like this:

```
  StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        ns.Add("", "");

        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer x = 
              new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(this.GetType());
        x.Serialize(sw, this,ns);

        return sw.ToString();
```

I want the child class/objects to have different names depending on a flag. is there a ways to change the ElementName of the class prop. during run time without write a custom WriteXml?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you won't like it. [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx)

Comment: It would be nice if somehow that we can make the attb of the prop conditional based on some flag.

Comment: That's not viable, because the whole point of XmlSerializer is that it reflects through your code JIT, then caches what it finds. Even if you could change attributes on the fly, the changes would be ignored. Sorry.

Comment: Actually, maybe you can hack around it. There are ways to control whether an element is emitted. What if you had two properties, each with their own element name, and only used one at a time?

Comment: Yeah that is what I figured. My other option was to create two duplicate class structures. one with a different set of element names. (YUK!)

Comment: Output 1: <product>value</product>

Output 2: <a100>value</a100>

this would be genereated from the same object

Comment: Can I programmatically turn on and off the xmlIgnore attr?

Comment: No, that's not the way I meant. I'm talking about ShouldSerialize* and *Specified.

Comment: See http://horacegoescoding.blogspot.com/2009/04/using-shouldserialize-for-conditional.html